# How to prevent widget from beeing scrolled?

Tags: flutter

How to prevent the first widget (ListView) from beeing scrolled?

The idea is to scroll `SomeList`, but the most top `ListView` widget should remain unscrollable.

```
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile( // how to prevet this widget from beeing scrolled?
                title: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Row(...),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SomeList(), // builds ListView.separated( ...
        ],
      ),
```

updated:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', home: MyListView());
  }
}

class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.black45,
                  child: Row(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Expanded(child: Text('Some header')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          RapportList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RapportList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RapportListState createState() => _RapportListState();
}

class _RapportListState extends State<RapportList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text('$index')),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const Divider();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is with `Expended` Widget,
use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` too. here is full code:

```
class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex:1,
              child: ListView(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      color: Colors.black45,
                      child: Row(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Text('Some header')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex:9,child: RapportList()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: as soon as I use the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics in the top most ListView the whole screen doesn't scroll anymore

Comment: use it in the second listview, the listview you don't want to scroll

Comment: @meditat in this case all the screen is scrollable again

Comment: @rozerro don't have Listview as parent widget use Column instead

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is following: scroll SomeList don't scroll firstList and container of both screens should not be scrollable.

Comment: if it is not what you are trying to achieve, you need to explain it better

Comment: @manofknowledge I think that's it "I try to achieve is following: scroll second List, while don't scroll first List and container of both lists should not be scrollable."

Comment: @manofknowledge Your last code dosn't work. With the top Column I get `A RenderFlex overflowed...` while the bottom list yet unscrollable.

Comment: @manofknowledge And if I wrap the top column with SingleChildScrollView then the whole screen is scrollable again.

Comment: renderflex exception is raised because Column height is over the screen `height`,
you can wrap `Column ` inside the `Container ` and give this `Container ` height of the screen with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`, I am gonna update the code again.

Comment: @manofknowledge this doesn't prevent from A RenderFlex overflowed... and the second (bottom) list isn't scrollable

Comment: @manofknowledge it works but there is a small gap under the first Expanded which is before the seconв list, wchich is not react on dragging (at least by mouse in emulator). How to reduce that area?

Comment: @rozerro manipulate the `flex` value inside `Expended`, this is a ratio,

Comment: ratio between both of the Expended widget's, you will understand when you play with them.

Answer (score 0):

Use physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() in Listview Then you can prevent your widget from beeing scrolled.